# Why DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns has a Browsable(false) attribute applied?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am just curious why the Windows DataGridView control is hiding its AutoGenerateColumns property from the designer?

Really can't come up with some nice answer to this question.
Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's hidden because it's controlled by a helper class. According to [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189576/datagridview-autogeneratecolumns-is-set-to-true-somehow), the Initialize() method of the DataGridViewDesigner (an undocumented and pretty well-hidden helper class) sets the DGV's AutoGenerateColumns property based on whether there is a DataSource specified, which overrides anything you might specify in your own code.

The logic would be that a DataSource is required in order to auto-generate columns; so, it would be invalid to let you try to set this property to True without having specified one. Conversely, if you're setting the DataSource in the designer, you probably want the DGV to set up the columns for you unless you've also set up your own using the Columns property.

You can expose this property by overriding it in a derived class and specifying a `[Browseable(true)]` attribute. However, as the question above shows, anything you set it to in a constructor or InitializeComponent() method will be overwritten by the DGVDesigner anyway.

Comment: Makes sense. I was just curious not really in a need to change it. It just made an impression on me. Anyway I am still wondering where's the difference between the Windows Forms DataGrid and its ASP.NET counter part. I mean if there is any tiny, curious thing that prevented the guys from implementing both controls the same way. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Makes sense *except that it's true by default*! So when constructing them sans-designer you have to be aware of this (somewhat) hidden property.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it's true by default is strange.
I always believe it is better to give the user ability to build up what he needs in the beginning instead of starting with what he most probably don't need and remove things until he / she gets the desired result. A Microsoft mistery :).