# DataGridView has too much columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms that contains a dataGridView. The datagridView contains 4 columns (1 checkbox, and 3 text).

When I load my form, I am loading data in a list of object (almost 15 attributes).

In my columns, I just have 3 values of my Objects that must be displayed, and the others will be use, programmatically, but not visible for the user.

The problem is, when I add the list as the DataSource of my GridView, I got the 3 columns, with values I want, but also 1 columns for each of the others attributes...

Why does the other columns appears, when I do not add them in my code?

I do not found the DataGridView property that will prevent this columns to be add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and bind columns manually by adding columns and setting data property

Comment: Do we know, Why this property doesn't appear in the design mode?(selecting the datagridView then properties). That's make it weird. I was thinking that, what we don't see in design mode, will not appear in programm mode...

Comment: I am not sure about my answer but i think, because datagridview can be used as bound and unbound mode so designer only show common properties which can be used in both modes.

Comment: Anyway, now, I know that for some properties, I must do it in programm mode. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` property of DataGridView as `false`

You can set this by code

```
datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
datagridview.DataSource = mydatasource;
```

Update :

This is property is browsable in ASP.net Gridview but not in WinForms in the designer

That is because this property set as  [browsable   false](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/9539.aspx)

read this for more info: 
[Why DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns has a Browsable(false) attribute applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095977/why-datagridview-autogeneratecolumns-has-a-browsablefalse-attribute-applied)

Comment: I do not found this : "unchek the box Auto Generate Fields" : Why this property doesn't appear in design mode (selecting the datagridView then properties), while it appears in programm mode?

Comment: @Zaphod Yes, remember this is on asp.net, but check on winforms and you are correct, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set [AutoGenerateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to **False**

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
```